# Find $d^3z$ of $z = x\cos(y)+y\sin(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, differential

Find $d^3z$ of $z = x\cos(y)+y\sin(x)$

**My Attempt**

$$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy = (\cos(y)+y\cos(x))dx + (-x\sin(y) + \sin(x))dy$$

$$d^2z = (-\sin(y)dy+\cos(x)dy - y\sin(x)dx)dx + (-\sin(y)dx -x\cos(y)dy + \cos(x)dx)dy $$
$$ =  - y\sin(x)dx^2 + (-2\sin(y)+ 2\cos(x))dxdy -x\cos(y)dy^2 $$

$$ d^3z =  (- \sin(x)dy -y\cos(x)dx)dx^2 + (-2\cos(y)dy - 2\sin(x)dx)dxdy+( -\cos(y)dx + x\sin(y)dy)dy^2 $$

$$ d^3z =  - \sin(x)dydx^2  -y\cos(x)dx^3 + -2\cos(y)dxdy^2 - 2\sin(x)dx^2dy) -\cos(y)dxdy^2 + x\sin(y)dy^3 $$

$$ d^3z =    -y\cos(x)dx^3 + -3\cos(y)dxdy^2 - 3\sin(x)dx^2dy)+ x\sin(y)dy^3 $$

Is this the correct approach / answer?

Comment: Is $d$ the exterior derivative?

Comment: . $d^2x = d(dx)$

Comment: You only tell us what is $d^2$ in terms of $d$. But what is $d$?

Comment: You should most definitely NOT use a differential forms tag. You are using $d$ inappropriately. You're trying to compute the Hessian $D^2z$ and third-order terms $D^3z$ in the Taylor expansion of $z$. These are symmetric tensors, nothing to do with differential forms.

Comment: I was able to confirm this to be the answer, problem is, I don't really know what I am computing (ie what does $d^3x$ mean?)